# Error installing pandas with pip: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3

Tags: pandas, numpy, pip

I'm trying to install pandas. When I run: `pip install pandas` in cmd, I get the following error message: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3`. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you have a different version of numpy installed, try upgrade `numpy` first with:

```
pip install numpy==1.9.3 --upgrade
```

then run `pip install pandas`. Also check this [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20697). Maybe your python version is not supported.

Comment: Python version was the problem. (I had been using 3.4). I uninstalled 3.4, installed 3.6.5, restarted everything, and it worked. Thanks!